# Piping commands into a NetCat shell on a Windows machine from Linux?

Tags: windows, shell, netcat

I'm working on a research project, which involves remoting into a Windows machine from Linux via NetCat. The command to open up a listener is

```
nc.exe -Ldp PORT -e cmd.exe
```

And the command to connect from Linux is

```
nc -v IP PORT
```

When issuing the second command on Linux, I'm dropped into a cmd shell in whatever directory NetCat is in. And then from here I can issue DOS commands willy-nilly.

But alas, I can't seem to pass NetCat a DOS command to execute from my Linux machine. It would be really cool if I could just pipe my DOS commands into the command to connect to the NetCat listener. Then I don't have to worry about connecting via Linux, waiting to drop into a CMD shell, and then issue my DOS command. I could just string 'em all together.

How can I pipe DOS commands into NetCat in Linux such that it connects to the Windows machine and executes my commands?

Comment: Just a heads up, if there's an easy fix, don't just post a comment. I can't award bounties on comments. If it answers the question regardless of brevity, post it as an answer. The first person who posts a workable solution gets the loot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would `printf 'whoami\r\n' | nc -v <ip> <port>` work?

Comment: I tried conventional Linux piping, no dice. And I looked into the command switches on NetCat: https://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf, but I can't find anything of interest there

Comment: Sorry -- see edit.

Comment: Also, some versions of netcat include a `-C` or a `--crlf` option. Does yours have that, and does that help?

Comment: Just gave it a go. NetCat says the connection succeeded but then it just drops me back at the Linux prompt instead of in the CMD shell.

Comment: My version does not have the -c option, but it's not a problem to switch versions. I'll give it a go...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45768/discussion-between-prateek61-and-verbal-kint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `cat` and have it wait on stdin.

`cat <( printf 'whoami\r\n' ) - | nc -v <host> <port>`

Comment: I don't exactly remember where I got this from, however I will provide the link when I find it.